# Hide top bar when scrolling down

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scroll

how can I obtain same or similar result to top bar in Google Keep app (Android) - which is always on and if we scroll down its hides. Similar is done in Chrome browser on Android.

It appear again when scrolling up.

[Valid XHTML http://img542.imageshack.us/img542/5980/unnamedap.jpg](http://img542.imageshack.us/img542/5980/unnamedap.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a 3rd party library that does that called [QuickReturn Listview](https://github.com/LarsWerkman/QuickReturnListView)

Answer (score 0):

Pretty awesome library for it here.
http://www.androidviews.net/2012/12/quickreturn-listview/